# How to access returned object from SOAP webservice using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am trying to consume a SOAP based webservice uisng PHP. Following is the sample code. I need to know/learn how to access the retur'ed object elements?
Please note i am new to PHP

```
    $url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL';
    $soap = new SoapClient($url, array(
        "trace"      => 1,      // enable trace to view what is happening
        "exceptions" => 0,      // disable exceptions
        "cache_wsdl" => 0) );
    try {
        $result = $soap->GetInfoByZIP(array('USZip' => '97219'));

        echo($result->$CITY);
        //print_r( $soap->GetInfoByZIP(array("USZip" => "97219")));
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo "Error: {$e->faultstring}";
    }
```

I get the following exception

```
Notice: Undefined variable: CITY 

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property
```

However when I execute the commented line above it return the following response

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [GetInfoByZIPResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => <NewDataSet xmlns=""><Table><CITY>Portland</CITY><STATE>OR</STATE><ZIP>97219</ZIP><AREA_CODE>503</AREA_CODE><TIME_ZONE>P</TIME_ZONE></Table></NewDataSet>
        )

)
```

So this means that data is being returned but i am not able to access it like the way done in .NET

Can anyone please help me how to access this object in PHP and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, u're using $CITY variable to access $result property and you haven't defined it yet.

So if you want to get "CITY" property inside "result" object you should do it by "$result->City".

According to result you get - it's a xml string, not object. If you want to access string do it this way:

```
$result->GetInfoByZIPResult->any
```

You can load string with DomDocument or simplexml lib.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
It apparently worked but when i try to print out the object it preints blank :/ but when i print object as XML it shows me the data. Need to know how to reference properties of object now :)
Here is the code


$obj = simplexml_load_string($result->GetInfoByZIPResult->any);
        echo $obj->asXML();

Comment: If you successfully converted XML string into an object, you can access it's properties as simple as that: $obj->Table->City.
And yes - dumping such objects has different behaviour from usuall.

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional help :)